# us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu Connection failed

Tags: apt, apache2

**ubuntu 18.04** Just installed, running

> apt update

returns, after a lot of time, a lot of issues like

```
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 0% [Waiting for headers]
```

The problem is, i can't install apache

```
apt install apache2
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried just everything, searching, but I think that this happens because of `apt update` which can't finish up in a correct way, and also the link http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu is not working for me, can it be from internet provider, does this link opening from you guys, and if yes, so what can i do for this?

Simple `apt update` makes a lot of trouble, which i never met before, stupid situation

1. I tried to change `/etc/resolv.conf`
   with

> ```
> #nameserver 8.8.8.8 
> #nameserver 8.8.4.4 
> nameserver 192.168.8.1
> ```

no result.

2.

```
apt clean
apt autoclean
```

3. removed the source.list `rm /etc/apt/sources.list` and lost a lot of data, which was inside, [from user answer #Anwar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which i am afraid made it worse.

4. Tried to change `http://us.archive.` to `http://old-releases.` no result

Any idea? This little problem makes impossible to use ubuntu.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: use the app 'software-properties-gtk' to rebuild the sources.list file

Comment: with 18.04 you'd better use the network-manager app to tune your dns  configuration, not resolv.conf